# Plesk Email Journaling

Tags: email, plesk

In regards to email archiving, How can I enable email journaling in Plesk?

```
OS               CentOS 6.4 (Final)
Panel version    11.5.30 Update #28
```

I've ready about editing /etc/antivirus.exim to do the following:

```
if $sender_address is monitored@address.com
then
 unseen deliver monitoring@address.com
endif
```

(reference: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/outgoing-mails-copy-39909.html)

However, I do not see a file under /etc/ named `antivirus.exim`. I understand that link is referring to cPanel mainly, but maybe this will spark some ideas in the minds of plesk/linux users.

Comment: There isn't a settings option to enable email journaling/archiving in Plesk. You can write a chron script to archive them by date, however, how to do so depends on your OS and the mail server installed for Plesk (there's a choice as to which during installation).

Comment: Looks like you updated this with your OS, and figured out below you've got Postfix installed (cPanel uses Exim). Thanks for adding what you've figured out too - nice job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've done this, and it seems to work. Weight in with your opinions.

Edit: /etc/postfix/main.cf and add (I added at the end of the file)

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc
```

Then create a new file: `/etc/postfix/sender_bcc` and add the following:

```
from@email.com to@email.com
anotherfrom@email.com anotherto@email.com
```

Then run the command `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_bcc && postfix reload`

It routes a copy of all outgoing mail from the first column of email addresses (from@) to the second column of email addresses (to@).